# C++11: Private member security

Tags: c++, c++11, private, auto

Let's consider the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mydemangled.hpp"

using namespace std;

struct A
{
private:
    struct B {
       int get() const { return 5; }
    };

public:
   B get() const { return B(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A::B b = a.get();

    cout << demangled(b) << endl;
    cout << b.get() << endl;
}
```

And the compiler (gcc 4.7.2) yells saying that `A::B` is private. All right.
So, I change the code:

```
int main()
{
   A a;

   cout << demangled(a.get()) << endl;
   cout << a.get().get() << endl;
}
```

and it doesn't yell:

```
$ ./a.out
A::B
5
```

Meaning, I can't to create instances of `A::B`, but I can use it.
So, new change (the key of my question).

```
int main()
{
   A a;
   auto b = a.get();

   cout << demangled(b) << endl;
   cout << b.get() << endl;
}
```

And output:

```
$ ./a.out
A::B
5
```

What is the trouble here, being `A::B` private (and thus its constructors, copy constructors and so on)?

Comment: `private` is not a security feature.

Comment: Security of access/exposition to the exterior I mean

Comment: That is interesting.  I'm still rusty with `auto` - does it perhaps become a `const A::B&`?  If it becomes `A::B`, how does it access the private copy constructor?

Comment: @Drew no, it becomes a `A::B`. This is not new in C++11, btw: `template <typename T> int f(T t) { return t.get(); } f(a.get());` works just fine too, because the rules are the same. You just cannot name the type.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I learned a thing!  Thanks.

Comment: Also, note how you can use the type indirectly inside the template function through T http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=89165da25c6b5f1311b88578cacc3f91-61c3814520a8d4318f681038dc4b4da7, or outside using decltype http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0dbdb6376ae43b6978a33e46110036ee-61c3814520a8d4318f681038dc4b4da7. The type itself is always usable (otherwise returning it from a public function would not make sense), you just cannot use its name. This is the same logic as allowing you to return references to private members, or pointers to private member functions.

Answer (score 5):

In general, access controls names or symbols, *not* the
underlying entities.  There are, and always have been, numerous
ways of accessing private members; what you cannot do is use the
name of such a member.

In your examples, you don't use the name, so there is no
problem.

Comment: To see this even better, try doing `typedef B OtherB;` in the public section of `A`. You'll see A::OtherB is accessible from main and `A::OtherB` works perfectly fine. The name itself is the one that's private, the type itself is perfectly accessible.