# private section of Qt classes is not safe

Tags: c++, qt, class, private-members

I have define a `QByteArray` `class` as `arr` instance in **Qt**. normally, `private` members of `QByteArray`(and another `classes`) are not accessible, else use of `friend` members in `class`.

Attention bellow code :

```
void Widget::onBtnRun()
{
    QByteArray arr;
    arr = "this is a test";
    arr.d->size = 5;                  // stop with compile error-> QByteArray::d is private
    QMessageBox::information(this, "", arr);
}
```

the `d` member of `QByteArray`  is `private` and cannot access to that!

but i have edited `QByteArray` `header` file, so adding bellow line in it's class section, then save that again.

```
public :
     friend Class Widget;
```

And now i can access to the `private` members of `QByteArray` `class` in `Widget` `class`, without any problem :

```
void Widget::onBtnRun()
{
    QByteArray arr;
    arr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV";
    arr.d->size = 5;
    QMessageBox::information(this, "", arr);
}
```

`MessageBox` output now is `"ABCDE"`.

Is this a lack for `classes`? perhaps this cause appear very problem in future.
how can save `private` members from thease problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what problems do you mean? Maybe a cleaner way would be to write a `getter` for the private member

Comment: I don't see how this is a problem. Since you're editing the header file, you might as well make private members public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class member access modifiers in C++ have nothing to do with security. They are there to **express design intent** that is enforced by the compiler. They are **not** used to "hide"/obfuscate code or prevent access by third parties.

Quoting [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15525524/1329652):

> In general, access controls names or symbols, not the underlying entities. There are, and always have been, numerous ways of accessing private members; what you cannot do is use the name of such a member.

Why do you consider this a problem? What are you trying to "protect" yourself/your code from?

Comment: yes , protected members cannot access, else in to the inherited class.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is **no way** to do this. If someone can access your header file, he could do potentially anything with your class. If you are developing a simple executable application, you should not worry about this because other users **cannot** access your source files. In case of library you can make  its dynamic and provide only .so/.dll file.

If you edit someone's header file, you will do it on your **own risk**.