# accessing private members from base class in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

In inheritance, if the base class is inherited publicly, can we access the `private` members of the base class if they are passed to the derived class by saving the address in a pointer and is part of `public` members in the derived class?  So now, can they be directly accessed in `main()` to be manipulated with?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    
public:
    int* a, * b;
    a = &width;
    b = &height;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
    void setWidth(int w) { *a = w; }
    void setHeight(int h) { *b = h; }
    int getArea() { return (*a * *b); }
};

int main() {
    Rectangle Rect;
    Rect.setWidth(5);
    Rect.setHeight(7);
    
    cout << "Total area: " << Rect.getArea() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, why do you need `a` and `b`? What are their purposes? What problem are they supposed to solve?

Comment: Secondly, you can't have general statements inside classes, it must be in a function like anything else.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525234/c11-private-member-security The private keyword is not about security, but about interface design. You can access private members from outside, as you tried to demonstrate (please make sure your code compiles next time). But you cannot access their *names* (`widh` and `height`) from outside of the class.

Comment: Access protection applies to names, not data.

Comment: The conventional way of getting a private member variable is to use a "getter" or "accessor", `int get_width() const { return width; }`.  And to set a private member variable is to use a "setter" or "mutator", `void set_width(int value) { width = value; }`.  Having getters/setters is often a code smell, and runs contrary to the Hollywood Principle, aka the "Tell, Don't Ask" Principle.

Comment: I have no idea what the goal is here, but please don't break encapsulation in this way.  If a member variable should be `protected`, make it `protected`.  If you want to keep it `private`, add getters and setters.  The end.

Comment: @joergbrech it is not a duplicate, here he tries to access the adress of a private member.

Comment: @kingsjester I mean, this question could be asking any one of 3 different questions, and I can't tell because it is poorly written.  The OP isn't clarifying as yet.  Is this a great question for other people to read and get good answers from?  If someone googled the keywords in this question, should they be given this question as a solution to their problem?

Comment: a base class can grant a derived class access to its private parts via its public members. Yes. `private` doesnt mean that there is absolutely no way to access it from outside, its rather to prevent accidential access. If you want to make it possible to access private members from outside there are ways

Comment: @kingjester being poorly written is just what downvotes are for (among other things). You are implying that some questions do not raise any interesting point and therefore should be downvoted, but thats rather odd imho. All quesitons are intersting, the mere fact that someone asks it makes it interesting, whether it can be improved or whether it is a good fit for SO is a differenst story

Comment: What is purpose of `Shape` here? It doesn't help at all. Looks like forcefully added inheritance. Just trash that inheritance. `Rectangle` without any ancestors is more natural and common.

Comment: An average sentence is about 15-20 words. The only sentence in this question is 54 words. That makes it very hard to parse, especially since there is no in-sentence punctuation to help. Don't try to cram everything into one sentence. *At a guess, you should have about twice as many words and five to six sentences to express what you are trying to ask.*

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question -

YES, the base class can expose `public` members that refer to its `private` members, and then outside code can use those `public` members to manipulate the `private` members.

However, the way you have approached it is syntactically wrong.  If you want to separate the *declarations* and *assignments* of `a` and `b` then you need to move the assignments into `Shape`'s constructor(s) instead, eg:

```
class Shape {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    
public:
    int *a, *b;

    Shape() {
        a = &width;
        b = &height;
    }

    // or:
    // Shape() : a(&width), b(&height) {}

    // don't forget about the copy/move constructors, too...

    Shape(const Shape &src) : Shape() {
        width = src.width;
        height = src.height;
    }

    Shape(Shape &&src) : Shape() {
        width = src.width;
        height = src.height;
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/KsryDt)

Otherwise, you can *initialize* `a` and `b` directly in their declaration statements, eg:

```
class Shape {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    
public:
    int *a = &width, *b = &height;

    Shape() = default;

    // don't forget about the copy/move constructors, too...

    Shape(const Shape &src) : Shape() {
        width = src.width;
        height = src.height;
    }

    Shape(Shape &&src) : Shape() {
        width = src.width;
        height = src.height;
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ORILgG)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, when a base class is inherited publicly, the public and protected members of the base class become public and protected members of the derived class, respectively. However, private members of the base class remain private in the derived class and are not directly accessible.
In your example, the private members width and height in the Shape class cannot be directly accessed in the Rectangle class or in the main function. Therefore, the code you provided will not compile successfully.

Also, this code is wrong

```
class Shape {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    
public:
    int* a * b;
    a = &
    b = &height;
};
```

In C++, you cannot have assignments (such as a = &width and b = &height) outside a function or constructor. In your case, these assignments need to be inside a constructor because the member variables (width and height) get initialized only when an object of the class is created.